# Showing overflow when reduced and expanded the screen again in my html page eventhough overflow is hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have an issue in my web page as given in this video(https://kapwi.ng/c/510TefvT).
when i decrease the screen size its responsive and in that decreased screen size when i scroll down and again changes the screen size back to desktop mode it show this overflow. below is the css and html of my page.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1071px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-left: 8%;
    padding-right: 8%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  nav {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
  }
  nav h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  nav span {
    color: #771633;
  }
  nav h6 {
    margin: 2px 20px;
  }
  .row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    /* margin: 70px 0; */
  }
  .col-1 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  .col-1 h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #771633;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  .col-1 p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-1 img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 1% 0;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  }
  .col-2 {
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 60%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
    margin-top: -10%;
  }
  .screen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22%;
    right: 2%;
    top: 2%;
  }
  .backgroundright {
    background-image: url('assets/Background.jpeg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 900px;
    height: 527px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 1000px 350px 900px 100px;
    transform: rotate(-9.85deg);
  }
  footer {
    position: relative;
  }
  #developedBy {
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-top: -4%;
    color: #929292;
  }
  .backgroundleft {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 68%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(assets/index.jpeg);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 200px 500px;
    transform: rotate(-179.57deg);
  }
  .fb {
    position: absolute;
    width: 3vw;
    height: 3vw;
    left: 2vw;
    top: 90%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  }
  /* twitter-social-logotype 2 */
  .twitter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 3vw;
    height: 3vw;
    left: 6vw;
    top: 90%;
    background: url(assets/twitter-social-logotype.png);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  }
  /* instagram 2 */
  .insta {
    position: absolute;
    width: 3vw;
    height: 3vw;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 90%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  }
  .social {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1070px) {
  * {
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  nav {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
  }
  nav h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  nav span {
    color: #771633;
  }
  nav h6 {
    margin: 2px 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .col-2 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .screen {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .backgroundright {
    display: none;
  }
  .backgroundleft {
    display: none;
  }
  .col-1 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    position: unset;
    top: 7%;
  }
  .col-1 h2 {
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #771633;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  .col-1 p {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 100%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-1 img {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0px 0;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-right: 0px;
    /* align-content: center; */
    justify-content: center;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  }
  #playstore {
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 15%;
  }
  #developedBy {
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: auto;
    color: #929292;
  }
  .footer {
    display: none;
  }
  .social {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .socialmedia {
    padding: 2% 5%;
    align-self: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">

  <div class="navbar">
    <nav>
      <h1>My<span class="wein">Webpage</span></h1>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <h2>Its a Web Page</h2>
      <p>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>
      <a href="https://play.google.com/store/">
        <img id="playstore" src="assets/playstoredownload.png" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.apple.com/in/app-store/">
        <img id="appstore" src="assets/appstoredownload.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <img src="assets/images.jpeg" alt="Image of a Phone" class="screen">
  <div class="backgroundright"></div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="backgroundleft"></div>

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
      <img src="assets/facebook-circular-logo.png" alt="" class="fb">
    </a>
    
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
      <img src="assets/instagram.png" alt="" class="insta">
    </a>
    
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/">
      <img src="assets/twitter-social-logotype.png" class="twitter" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="social">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
    <img src="assets/facebook-black.png" alt="" class="socialmedia" height="30vh" width="30vh">
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
    <img src="assets/instagram-black.png" alt="" class="socialmedia" height="30vh" width="30vh"> 
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/">
    <img src="assets/twitter-black.png" alt="" class="socialmedia" height="30vh" width="30vh">
  </a>
</div>

<h6 id="developedBy">Developed by abcdefg</h6>
```

is there any solution for this?